# How to calculate Power Point total for multi-calss manifesters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, psionics

I'm currently playing an [Aegis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/) Lv6 and want to dip a few levels in [Vitalist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/vitalist/#TOC-Vitalist-Methods) to aid my party cleric...mostly out of combat.

I have an Int 18 and Wis 16. According [Ability Modifiers and Bonus Power Points](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/) chart Aegis get a 9 PP at Lv6 + 12 more for high Int at Lv6. Vitalist get 2 PP at Lv1 + 1 more at Lv1 for high Wis. Do I just add these all up for a total at Lv7 or is the bonus PP you get equal to your Total Level?

Like Aegis get a 9 PP at Lv + 14 more for high Int being a 7th Lv PC. Vtialist get 2 PP at Lv1 + 10 more at for high Wis being a 7th Lv PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out your power points from each class, and then add them together.¹ For the “high ability score” table, you use your **manifester level** for each class—not your total character level. So since a 6th-level aegis has 9 + 3×Int power points,¹ and a 1st-level vitalist has 2 + ½×Wis power points,¹ a 6th-level aegis/1st-level vitalist has 9 + 3×Int + 2 + ½×Wis power points.¹ With Int 18 and Wis 16, that’s 9 + 12 + 2 + 1½ = 24½ = 24 (cuz we always round down).²

You only have one pool of power points and can use that for anything you use power points on—aegis customizations, vitalist powers, and so on.

1. <sub>This is all assuming you don’t have any bonus power points from your race, feats, items, or whatever. If you *do* have any of those things, those get added *after* figuring out your base power points from your class and bonus power points from high ability scores. So if you are naturally psionic and have 2 bonus power points from your race, a 6th-level aegis has 9 + 3×Int + 2 power points, a 1st-level vitalist has 2 + ½×Wis + 2 power points, and a 6th-level aegis/1st-level vitalist has 9 + 3×Int + 2 + ½×Wis + 2 power points (not +4 at the end, which you’d get if you added the +2 to each class and then added those together). Also, if you have bonuses to aegis and/or vitalist manifester level, you might have higher multipliers than 3× and ½×, respectively, since those numbers are based on your manifester level in each class.</sub>
2. <sub>The table for the bonus power points from high ability scores lists just “1” for the bonus at 1st level and a score of 16—that’s because the numbers in the table are rounded down. The formula is ½×ML×ability modifier, so ½×1×3 in this case, for 1½. It doesn’t really matter here.</sub>